# TClientDataSet.Locate do not handle accents

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

As I wrote in the title, I have an issue with the component `TClientDataSet` and specially with its method [Locate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.Locate). If there is an accent in the searched string, the returned value is always false, and there is no option to handle accents in the [TLocateOption](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TLocateOptions). Did anyone found a way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

--- EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
// in a method
ClientDataSetTournee.open;

// in an other method that I call after in a separate thread
// libtor equals 'ANTONY_CLSH TOURNÉE 1 (VACANCES)'
if ClientDataSetTournee.Locate('LIBTOR', libtor, []) then
begin
    // data found
end
else
begin
    myShowMessage('Erreur', 'Erreur interne : tournée introuvable' );
    exit;
end;
```

`ClientDataSetTournee` is fill thanks to the `ProviderName` that get the data from server and when libtor have this value, the error message shows up.

Comment: Well, MIDAS is a problem. I would get rid of it. It should be deprecated. Forever. If you have FireDAC and the opportunity to migrate, do so. Or to another modern client library. That's the best I can say.

Comment: @Victoria isn't TClientDataSet became pure pascal with on of the Delphi versions?

Comment: Found the answer By adding midaslib to the uses list no need for the dll. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29297

Comment: @RM., great, it statically links precompiled MIDAS library objects into the binary. Still, what does it change? Even publishing (e.g. as open) source would not make MIDAS anyhow modern. IMHO, MIDAS needs to be burned no matter what. EMBT bought AnyDAC (to become FireDAC) for a reason.

Comment: @RM: It still links in the Midas code, which is not written in Delphi (it's C++). Just because they provide object (.obj) files that get linked in when you add MidasLib doesn't magically convert all of that code into Delphi code. See your BDS folder, in `source\data\dsnap\midas` for some of the source and header files.

Comment: Adding MidasLib does makes sure your using the correct version of midas intended for your delphi version, not a midas dll that was registered from an older delphi version for example. Otherwise it changes nothing.

Comment: @Victoria ok got it. What is the problem with TClientDataSet? I have heard from my colleges that there are big projects using it without problems.

Comment: @Manon I just wrote a small application to test this and it is working fine (XE2). Do you have an example where this is not working?

Comment: @RM. The command that is not working is this one :

`ClientDataSetTournee.Locate('LIBTOR', libtor, [])`

And `libtor` is equal to something like `TOURNÉE 1 (VACANCES)`, when I remove the `É` it works fine

Comment: @Manon I tried with this text and it is working fine. Please provide a complete example which fails so I can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

program Project129;

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Datasnap.DBClient,
  Data.DB;

procedure DoTest;
var
  dataSet: TClientDataSet;
  varFieldDef: TFieldDef;
begin
  dataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    with dataSet.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef do
    begin
      Name := 'Name';
      DataType := ftString;
    end;

    dataSet.CreateDataSet;
    dataSet.Append;
    dataSet.FieldByName('Name').AsString := 'TOURNÉE 1 (VACANCES)';
    dataSet.Post;

    if dataSet.Locate('Name', 'TOURNÉE 1 (VACANCES)', []) then
      WriteLn('Found')
    else
      WriteLn('Not found');

    ReadLn;
  finally
    dataSet.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  DoTest;
end.
```

The output of the application is "Found"

Comment: I edited my post. I tried your code and it works, so I don't understand why my code is not working. The difference is that I don't create and fill the dataset by code...